# \pagestyle{ruled} adds superfluous text in glossary

Tags: header-footer, memoir, glossaries, incompatibility

I'm writing my thesis using the memoir package, using `\pagestyle{ruled}`, and have created glossaries for a glossary and an acronym list. The resulting pdf, contains the superfluous text "Glossary" and "Acronyms" right below the chapter headings of the same name.

I use latexmk to build the pdf, using a custom `.latexmkrc`:

```
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries {
    system("makeglossaries '$_[0]'");
}
```

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\pagestyle{ruled}
\newglossaryentry{UML}{name={UML},description={definition}}
\newacronym{XML}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
text \gls{XML}
\gls{UML}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Removing the `\pagestyle{ruled}` line removes the extra text.
How do I get rid of the extra text, while still using a ruled pagestyle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue `\pagestyle{ruled}` *before* loading the `glossaries` package. (I've tested my solution with a glossary with about 30 entries, and its page style is indeed `ruled`.)

Partial explanation: Both `memoir` and `glossaries` define the `\glossarymark` macro. `glossaries` adds some compatibility code in case `memoir` is used, and so it seems the sensible thing to choose a page style first and then let `glossaries` do its work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{UML}{name={UML},description={definition}}
\newacronym{XML}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
text \gls{XML}
\gls{UML}
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yay! It works, thanks. BTW: It does not work when the `\pagestyle{ruled}` command is invoked again after the `\usepackage{glossaries}`.

Comment: Is there any other caveat letting you load `glossaries` before the `\pagestyle` command?

Comment: @rowman None that I know of. OTOH, the one at hand is big enough. ;-)

Comment: As a note, version 3.17a or later of glossaries has this fixed.