# Getting rid of Glossary text in glossary in memoir style (Bug?)

Tags: memoir, glossaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\pagestyle{ruled} adds superfluous text in glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28659/pagestyleruled-adds-superfluous-text-in-glossary)

I would like to get rid of the glossary in the first line after header. How can I do that? `lualatex` and `makeglossaries` is used.

[image]

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{main-acro.tex}
\newacronym{pdms}{PDMS}{Poly-dimethyl-siloxane}
\newacronym{dc}{DC}{Direct current}
\newacronym{ac}{AC}{Alternative current}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}% to allow multicollumn glossaries

\makepagestyle{genomics}
\makepsmarks{genomics}{%
  \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\pagestyle{genomics}

\loadglsentries{main-acro}
\makeglossaries
\glsaddall    % add all the glossary regardless of them being used.
\renewcommand*{\glsmcols}{2}  
\glossarystyle{mcolindex} 

\begin{document}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

I found the culprit during making a MWE. it it the `createplainmark` line. If you comment that out, everything is OK. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you provide a complete minimal example that can be tested?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, MWE added.

Comment: @rowman This is a duplicate of the link provided by @lockstep. It's not so much a bug as an incompatibility between `memoir` and `glossaries`. The workaround is the same as the answer to the other question.

Comment: @rowman Please try the solution at the link that lockstep provided.  If that solves the issue then that's great and we'll close this question as a duplicate of that one.  If it doesn't then please edit the question to explain why the solution there doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I tried that solution it worked. That's good. But is there any other caveat not to change the ordering of packages? I have quite a big preamble and it gets a bit unorganized if I do this.

Comment: @rowman You should leave that as a comment on the answer to the duplicate question.  I don't actually know anything about this question, I was merely encouraging you to try that solution and explain how best to get help if it didn't work.

Comment: As a note, version 3.17a or later of glossaries has this fixed.